# YouTube API iFrame - Keep YouTube video iFrame playing while phone locked

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I would like to know if it is possible to keep a YouTube API iFramme video playing while my phone is locked.
I mean, I'm using the YouTube API iFrame to embed a YouTube video on my website. But when I lock my phone, the video stops playing. However, when I lock my computer, the video continues playing.
How can I "fake" a "desktop iFrame" or how can I force, in JS, the video to play?

Thanks!

EDIT: I tried something like this:

```js
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    player.playVideo()
}
```

It works only on some phones, but not for all...

It is not a problem if I can't stop playing the video after: it's for streaming, so I just have to mute the video if I want to "stop" it.

Comment: I have adblocker browser on my android smartphone and *sometimes* when I lock my smartphone while a YouTube video is playing on the said browser, the video keeps playing. However, I cannot reproduce this effect all times - probably each 2 of 10. This *might* be a bug on the browser, but, you might check it out and see what you can find.